# Why Auth::user(); gives different data from loged-in user? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I try to make login using Auth, its work seems fine but when I check the stored/logged-in data user is different.

here's the code in **authController**

```
  public function auth(Request $request)
  {
    $rules = [
      'username' => 'required|string',
      'password' => 'required|string'
    ];
    $msg = [
      'username.required' => 'wajib isi username',
      'username.string' => 'not username',
      'password.required' => 'wajib isi password',
      'password.string' => 'string password',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $msg);
    if($validator->fails()){
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all());
    }

    $data = [
      'userid' => $request['username'],
      'password' => $request['password']
    ];
    Auth::attempt($data);
    if(Auth::check()){
      dd(Auth::user());
      return redirect('dashboard');
    }else{
      Session::flash('error', 'ada yang salah ops!');
      // return redirect('login');
    }
  }
```

when I 'dd(Auth::user());' after Auth::check() the data is correct, **example**

[image: dd(Auth::user()); result]

Then I check it on the dashboard page with the following code in **adminController**

```
    public function dashboard()
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
        return view('admin/masterdata/blank');
    }
```

It's given me this result

[image]

and here's my User model look like

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nama', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**UPDATE**
and here is my `config/auth.php`

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Is the words `users` in `config/auth.php` mean the `users` model?

Is something wrong with my code or something I miss?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your middlewares leading to the dashboard.

Comment: `'userid' => $request['username'],` to `'email' => $request['username'],` fix this

Comment: @KamleshPaul I didn't have an email column, and try login using userid

Comment: Check your `config/auth.php` and `config('auth.guards')` if set correctly.

Comment: oh not sure `attempt()` accept other key or not you can use `$user = User::where()` then `auth()->login($user)`

Comment: @N69S I didn't change any middlewares

Comment: @ElektaKode I didn't see any `config('auth.guards')` in `config/auth.php`

Comment: hi @KamleshPaul  N69S ElektaKode I update the question you may take a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this other way as you have `userid` and `password` to check for login

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ];
    $msg = [
        'username.required' => 'wajib isi username',
        'username.string' => 'not username',
        'password.required' => 'wajib isi password',
        'password.string' => 'string password',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $msg);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all());
    }

    $user = User::where('userid', $request['username'])->first();
    if (!$user) {
        return redirect()->with('error', 'user not found.');
    }

    if (Hash::check($request['password'],$user->password);) {
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
        Session::flash('error', 'ada yang salah ops!');
    }
}
```

then try  in `adminController.php`

```php
public function dashboard()
{
    dd(Auth::user());
    return view('admin/masterdata/blank');
}
```

here i used `auth()->login($user);` to login valid user

Comment: @KamleshPaul I `Hash` the password, should I hash here too?

Comment: it `Hash::check()` not `Hash::make()`

Comment: it's work, but after in dashboard page `dd(Auth::user());` it's giving me a different result, like in my question

Comment: then may be somewhere your changing that login user